# How to get XeLaTeX do proper hyphenation and full justification?

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, margins, hyphenation

I want to use XeLaTeX to design a paperback (11x19cm) using Adobe's Garamond and Myriad as custom fonts. It is entirely written in German.

However, both hyphenation and full justification are a mess: in my MWE there are four breaks in four lines and the German Umlaut "ß" seems to cause a problem as well.

And here comes my MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding =UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt,headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=11cm,paperheight=19cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}


\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont {Minion Pro} % Main document font
\setsansfont {Myriad Pro} % Heading font


\begin{document}
\chapter{Die Berge -- eine erfundene Idylle}
Weit hinten, hinter den Wortbergen, fern der Länder Vokalien und Konsonantien leben die Blindtexte. Abgeschieden wohnen Sie in Buchstabhausen an der Küste des Semantik, eines großen Sprachozeans. Ein kleines Bächlein namens Duden fließt durch ihren Ort und versorgt sie mit den nötigen Regelialien. Es ist ein paradiesmatisches Land, in dem einem gebratene Satzteile in den Mund fliegen. Nicht einmal von der allmächtigen Interpunktion werden die Blindtexte beherrscht – ein geradezu unorthographisches Leben. Eines Tages aber beschloß eine kleine Zeile Blindtext, ihr Name war Lorem Ipsum, hinaus zu gehen in die weite Grammatik. Der große Oxmox riet ihr davon ab, da es dort wimmele von bösen Kommata, wilden Fragezeichen und hinterhältigen Semikoli, doch das Blindtextchen ließ sich nicht beirren.
\end{document}
```

And here is the not-so-nice output:
[image]

Comment: Oops, paperback size is 12x19cm, so this partly explains the problems with the narrow layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a pretty narrow text width; the ratio between the text width and the average width of letters is 36, so you can't have many letters on a line and with the long German words hyphenation will certainly be more frequent. The word "fließt" has no break points. You can try loading `microtype` (the 2.8 beta version), but either you allow larger interword space, increasing the tolerance, or you have to live with frequent hyphenation.

Here's an attempt.

```
\documentclass[11pt,headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=11cm,paperheight=19cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{microtype} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,latesthyphen=true]{german}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % Main document font
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro} % Heading font

\hyphenpenalty=1000 % default 50
\tolerance=500      % default 200

\begin{document}
\chapter{Die Berge -- eine erfundene Idylle}

Weit hinten, hinter den Wortbergen, fern der Länder Vokalien und 
Konsonantien leben die Blindtexte. Abgeschieden wohnen Sie in Buchstabhausen 
an der Küste des Semantik, eines großen Sprachozeans. Ein kleines Bächlein 
namens Duden fließt durch ihren Ort und versorgt sie mit den nötigen 
Regelialien. Es ist ein paradiesmatisches Land, in dem einem gebratene
Satzteile in den Mund fliegen. Nicht einmal von der allmächtigen 
Interpunktion werden die Blindtexte beherrscht – ein geradezu 
unorthographisches Leben. Eines Tages aber beschloß eine kleine Zeile 
Blindtext, ihr Name war Lorem Ipsum, hinaus zu gehen in die weite Grammatik. 
Der große Oxmox riet ihr davon ab, da es dort wimmele von bösen Kommata, 
wilden Fragezeichen und hinterhältigen Semikoli, doch das Blindtextchen 
ließ sich nicht beirren.

\end{document}
```

[image: 11x19]

This is the result with the very same input, with only 12cm for the paper width.

[image: 12x19]

Comment: I could not fully reproduce this, as I could not find a way yet to install microtype for XeLaTeX. I opened another thread for this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100300/16868

Comment: @MartinBetz Sorry, but I can't help for that: MiKTeX refuses to run on any of my machines. ;-)

Comment: @egrep: No problem. But I guess, an advice for TeXLive or MacTeX would be helpful as well...