# How to install microtype 2.8 beta?

Tags: installing, microtype

I want to test microtype 2.8 beta, to get better typography support for XeLaTeX as proposed [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100299/16868). However, I could not find any reference online how to install the latest beta version, neither for my system MikTeX nor for TexLive or MacTex.

How to install it?

Comment: Could it be a dublicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32508/install-a-beta-package-from-tlcontrib-on-mactex-2011-tex-live

Comment: For miktex (which is not mentioned in the duplicate): Put all the files in a folder `whatever/tex/latex/microtype/` (whatever should be outside miktex and can be e.g. an existing local texmf tree). Then add `whatever` in miktex settings as a new root.

Comment: See also [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).